# Not authorized to control networking from cron

Tags: networking, cron

I am using the command `nmcli c up id networkname` to change the network in a script. The script works fine when I run from the terminal, but when I run the script from cron, I get an error:

```
Error: Connection activation failed: Not authorized to control networking.
```

Searching online, I found a bug report from 2011 about this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/681708, but no resolution.

Why does the script work when run from terminal, but not from cron? I would like to avoid putting this in the root's cron if possible.

Comment: I've got the same problem. It seems you need to be logged into X for some reason. Have you tried to do this from the tty (ctrl-alt-F1)? What linx dist/version are you on?

Answer (score 14):

### PolKit

The daemon deciding whether to give access to your script is called polkitd.

To get some information on what is going wrong you can issue

```
nmcli general permissions
```

It will list some permissions related to `nmcli`. You will note that running from cron and while logged in while give different results.

Current dists (such as Ubuntu and more) aimed at desktop use, uses the permission Active alot, meaning it will grant access to users logged in into a local and active X11 session.

You can also run polkitd in a terminal like so

```
killall polkitd  # first kill running polkitd
G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd
```

This will allow you to see what polkitd is doing and what decisions it's making.

### Solution

Add a .pkla file in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/`, call it e.g. `x.pkla`. **Imortant:** It needs to be sorted lexicographical after other e.g. `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pkla` or that file will override your cute file.

Put in something like this to grant permission to users in the `adm`group. You can also grant to a specific users, etc.

```
[Let adm group modify system settings for network]
Identity=unix-group:adm
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system
ResultAny=yes
```

You might need to add multiple sections to this file if you need more permissions, such as enable/disable wifi.

Comment: 'nmcli general permissions'
Error: Object 'general' is unknown, try 'nmcli help'.

Comment: ah, yes, you get that when your nmcli version is too old. Everything else regarding `polkitd`, just there is no easily accessible way to see what nmcli has permissions to do, from it's own perspective.

Comment: In the DEBUG messages it says, among other things: `DEBUG: 09:31:51.979: Added /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d' as a local authorization store`. Seems like that'd be a more "normal" place to put custom config files, no?

Comment: On CentOS 7, `systemctl restart polkit` was sufficient to apply config from the new `.pkla` files.

Comment: On Ubuntu, you can restart `polkit` with : `sudo systemctl restart polkitd`

Comment: @partofthething why would that be a more "normal" place. In the documentation it's for 3rd-party library. Place it in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/` as described in the answer.

Answer (score 9):

The solution descripted by @vidstige helped me to solve the problem. As @partofthething commented the question is, if `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/` is the best place to store the .pkla.

After reading [`man pklocalauthority`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/pklocalauthority.8.html) I think not.

> The /etc/polkit-1/localauthority hierarchy is inteded for local configuration and the /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority is intended for 3rd party packages.

Do we build a 3rd party package? I think not.

> 10-vendor.d is intended for use by the OS vendor.

Do we are a OS vendors? I think not.

I think `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/`is the better place the .pkla.

Using this way also solves the problem with the sorting:

1. `50-local.d` is evaluated after `10-vendor.d`
2. `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/` is evaluated after  `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority`

(I would write this a comment, but the 50 reputation…)